Transient analysis of RC DC circuit
The task is to find the current that flows through capacitor C. I tried to analyse the circuit using mesh analysis but failed. I need to find the current through C during switching (t=0) and steady-state (t=infinity).

I tried but I think this solution is not going anywhere. Can you help me please?

May we assume that the voltage across each capacitor starts with 0 V?

Perhaps it's OK if I help you by saying that the starting current (t=0) is E/R. The steady state current (t=infinite) is zero. These are the values you need to arrive at based on your calculations.(The initial voltage of the capacitors is zero.)

hipigeons, Is there something more you need to know? Or are you done?

Your question is a good segue for how Laplace is an excellent partner for solving time domain questions. It's so beautiful. One can first cast the problem in very simple terms with the s operator (\$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\$) so that very easy-to-use algebra can be applied to set up the problem. Then annihilation can be applied to make the equations homogeneous (simple) and from there standard time-domain solutions that can be grabbed up and applied. Nice. Hopefully the following illustrates the wonderful partnership between time domain and Laplace.
KCL approach
I've added some annotations for use with KCL:

I labeled the top node as \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$ only because I felt like it. But it is your \$\mathscr{E}\$ source over on the left.
KCL says:
eq1 = Eq( v1*s*C + v1/R + v1/R, v2/R + vin*s*C )           # KCL node V1
eq2 = Eq( v2/R + v2/R + v2*s*2*C, v1/R + vin*s*2*C )       # KCL node V2
simplify( vin - solve( [ eq1, eq2 ], [ v1, v2 ] )[v1] )    # applied capacitor voltage
vin*(2*C*R*s + 3)/(2*C**2*R**2*s**2 + 6*C*R*s + 3)         # final Vc result

finding the general solution form
A simple manipulation gets things started:
$$\begin{align*}
V_{_\text{C}}&= V_{_\text{IN}}\frac{2 R C s+3}{2 R^2 C^2 s^2 + 6 R C s + 3}
\\\\
\therefore
\\\\
\left[2 R^2 C^2 s^2 + 6 R C s + 3\right]V_{_\text{C}}&= \left[2 R C s+3\right]V_{_\text{IN}}
\end{align*}$$
Note that you can simply multiply both sides by the denominator on the right, in the first equation. The second equation just reads differently, saying now that the result you get from applying the differential operator on the left to \$V_{_\text{C}}\$ is the same as when applying the differential operator on the right to \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$.
The s terms (which are just simple derivative operators), when applied to a constant-valued \$V_{_\text{IN}}\$, are just zero. So those terms can be removed and the above reduces to:
$$\begin{align*}
\left[2 R^2 C^2 s^2 + 6 R C s + 3\right]V_{_\text{C}}&= 3 V_{_\text{IN}}
\\\\
\left[s\vphantom{R^2}\right]\left[2 R^2 C^2 s^2 + 6 R C s + 3\right]V_{_\text{C}}&= 0
\\\\
\left[s\vphantom{\frac3{R\, C}}\right]\left[s^2 + \frac3{R\, C} s + \frac3{2 R^2 C^2}\right]V_{_\text{C}}&= 0
\end{align*}$$
(The second step multiplies both sides by the differential operator s, which causes the remaining constant value on the right side to go to zero. The goal is to make the equation homogeneous.)
The third equation there is homogeneous and in the standard form where a general form for the solution exists.
The bracketed, isolated s is actually \$\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}-\alpha\right)\$ where \$\alpha=0\$. (The \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\$ is the same as s.) This form is solved by \$A_1\cdot\exp\left(\alpha\cdot t\right)\$. Which is just \$A_1\$ in this case since \$\alpha=0\$.
The remaining bracketed factor needs to be put into this form: \$\left[\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}-\alpha\right)^2+\omega^2\right]\$. This form is solved by \$A_2\cdot\exp\left(\alpha\,t\right)\cdot\left[\cos\left(\omega\,t\right)+A_3\cdot\sin\left(\omega\,t\right)\right]\$.
We can get this last part handled. If \$A=\frac3{R\, C}\$ and \$B=\frac3{2\, R^2\, C^2}\$ then \$\alpha=-\frac12 A=-\frac3{2\,R\, C}\$ and \$\omega=\sqrt{B-\alpha^2}\$.
Putting both together gives the general form of the solution:
$$V_{_\text{C}(t)}=A_1+A_2\cdot\exp\left(\alpha\,t\right)\cdot\left[\cos\left(\omega\,t\right)+A_3\cdot\sin\left(\omega\,t\right)\right]$$
finding the specific solution
If \$\omega\$ is imaginary then the behavior is over-damped and the hyperbolic versions of sine and cosine will show up in the solution, instead.
In this case, it must always be imaginary as \$\omega=\sqrt{-\frac3{4\,R^2\,C^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2\,R\,C}=j\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\,R\,C}\$.
So, set \$\omega^{'}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\,R\,C}\$ (substituting \$\omega=j\,\omega^{'}\$) and find:
$$V_{_\text{C}(t)}=A_1+A_2\cdot\exp\left(\alpha\,t\vphantom{\omega^{'}\,t}\right)\cdot\left[\cosh\left(\omega^{'}\,t\right)+j\,A_3\cdot\sinh\left(\omega^{'}\,t\right)\right]$$
(Note that \$\alpha=\sqrt{3}\,j\,\omega=-\sqrt{3}\,\omega^{'}\$.)
From initial conditions at \$t=0\$ and knowing the final voltage across the capacitor at \$t=\infty\$ find \$A_1=V_{_\text{IN}}\$ and \$A_2=-V_{_\text{IN}}\$. So:
$$V_{_\text{C}(t)}=V_{_\text{IN}}\left(1-\exp\left(\alpha\,t\vphantom{\omega^{'}\,t}\right)\cdot\left[\cosh\left(\omega^{'}\,t\right)+j\,A_3\cdot\sinh\left(\omega^{'}\,t\right)\right]\right)$$
At this point, take the derivative, set \$t=0\$ to simplify, multiply by \$C\$ and get the initial current, which must be \$\frac{V_{_\text{IN}}}{R}\$. This finds \$A_3=-\frac{\alpha+\frac1{R\,C}}{j\,\omega^{'}}\$. So the final specific result is:
$$\begin{align*}V_{_\text{C}(t)}&=V_{_\text{IN}}\left(1-\exp\left(\alpha\,t\vphantom{\omega^{'}\,t}\right)\cdot\left[\cosh\left(\omega^{'}\,t\right)-\frac{\alpha+\frac1{R\,C}}{\omega^{'}}\cdot\sinh\left(\omega^{'}\,t\right)\right]\right)
\\\\
&=V_{_\text{IN}}\left(1-\exp\left(\alpha\,t\vphantom{\omega^{'}\,t}\right)\cdot\left[\cosh\left(\omega^{'}\,t\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\cdot\sinh\left(\omega^{'}\,t\right)\right]\right)
\end{align*}$$
getting the capacitor's current
Now you can take the derivative of the above specific equation and multiply it again by \$C\$ to get the specific equation for current of the capacitor over time, as well:
$$I_{_\text{C}(t)}=\frac{V_{_\text{IN}}}{R}\cdot\exp\left(\alpha\,t\vphantom{\omega^{'}\,t}\right)\cdot \cosh\left(\omega^{'}\,t\right)$$
simulation
It's one thing to apply theory. It's another to have it confirmed through simulation.
So I'll use \$C=10\:\mu\text{F}\$, \$R=10\:\text{k}\Omega\$, and \$V_{_\text{IN}}=10\:\text{V}\$.

The two plot panels each have two curves on them. As you can see, the two currents over time shown in the top panel are exactly on top of each other. And the same is also true for the two applied capacitor voltages plotted on the bottom panel. One each is directly from the schematic analysis by LTspice and the other comes from the .FUNC cards that reflect the equations developed above.
Clearly, they reproduce each other perfectly well.
So this shows that simulation adds confirmation, through an entirely independent method, for the above mathematical approach.
summary
That provides both the voltage across, and the current, for the indicated capacitor in your circuit as a function of time, starting at \$t=0\$. (Useless for \$t\lt 0\$.)
Also, remembering that \$\alpha=\sqrt{3}\,j\,\omega=-\sqrt{3}\,\omega^{'}\$ feel free to propagate the exp function into the cosh and/or sinh functions if you prefer that alternate form. I don't, though.

Theoretical calculations of currents and voltages according to the mesh method. I don't notice the excitement. I used s instead of p as a complex variable. In the example below I considered constant excitement.(I have made extensive use of MATHCAD 15 and Windows PAINT for the graphs.The negative sign of the iC(t) indicates that it is contrary to that established in the digraph ).


It seems that your equations are ok.
I found this using a Maple sheet.


can I use KCL at the node between i, i(c) and i1? So it will become (i11-i22)-(i22-i33)-(i11-i33)=0. The result will be i33=i22

The result should be equal to 0 ... i=i33-i22.

can you help me how to get the equation of ic(t)? is it second order circuit or not
